# Sharepoint / Flow Automatically add a revision to a document that's been rejected

Tags: workflow-activity, approval

When a document has been rejected using the approval flow, can I then add an action within the flow to revise the document, ie create a new revision with the status for approval. If the document has been approved it stays as the current revision with the status approved.

Comment: You can always use the `Update Item` action in your Flow.  If version history is turned on for this list/library, that action creates a new version.

Comment: Add the condition on the approval status to check if it is "Approved" or "Rejected". Then in "Rejected" block use the Update Item action on the same item.